# Can't load W3 page using IE, but Chrome and Firefox can

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, browser, internet-explorer

Does anyone know why IE can't load the page: https://www.w3.org/TR/xmldsig-core/xmldsig-core-schema.xsd or http://www.w3.org/TR/xmldsig-core/xmldsig-core-schema.xsd but Firefox and Chrome can?

- IE version: 11.0.9600.18282
- Chrome version: 51.0.2704.36 beta-m (64-bit)
- Firefox version: 49.0a1 (2016-05-07)

Comment: No repro on Windows 7 64 bit, IE 11.0.9600.17691CO

Comment: Are you able to provide a screenshot of the error you receive? Are there errors in the developer console (press `F12`)?

Comment: I think this is a cryptographic suite issue.